# Carrierwave: Конвертирование любого формата видео в mp4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Не могу понять как пользоваться гемом `carrierwave` для конвертирования видео. Я загружаю видео различных форматов. Все видео должны сохраняться в БД с расширением `mp4` т.е. конвертироваться. Я так понимаю гем `carrierwave_video` это может.

Думал эта строка в Uploader сработает,но нет:

```
process :encode_video=> [:mp4]
```

Вот код VideoUploader:

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::FFmpeg
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  version :mp4 do
    process :encode_video=> [:mp4, audio_codec: "aac",:custom => "-strict experimental -q:v 5 -preset slow -g 30"]
    def full_filename(for_file)
      "#{File.basename(for_file, File.extname(for_file))}.mp4"
    end
  end

  version :ogv, :from_version => :mp4 do
    process :encode_ogv => []
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Исходный формат - mpg, в таком и сохраняется.

Как конвертировать любой загружаемый формат видео в mp4 с помощью гема `carrierwave_video`?

Comment: Какой был формат, в таком и сохраняет....

Comment: то есть вы делаете на полученном файле mp4 - `file file.mp4` и но выдаёт что де файл mpg так?

Comment: Я выбираю файл с расширением mpg, он сохраняет файл в формате mpg. А должен в mp4 конвертировать.

Comment: Погодите, как вы убеждаетесь, что полученный файл в формате mpg?